# Can slice in Go be multiplied like Python's list?

Tags: python, go

Here is the Python example:

```py
s = ["push", "pop"] * 10
```

How to do that in Go?

Comment: While it might be obvious what does, you still should explain what you want to achieve. Also (against downvoting), the language is 'Go' or 'go' and you might want to state what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply with a for loop. There is nothing builtin.

```
in := []string{"push", "pop"}

n := 10
out := make([]string, 0, len(in)*n) // allocate space for the entire result
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {            // for each repetition...
    out = append(out, in...)        // append, append, ....
}

fmt.Println(out) // prints [push pop push pop push pop push pop push pop push pop push pop push pop push pop push pop]
```

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to write a generic multiplier:

```
// multiply repeats the slice src n times to the slice pointed to by destiny.
func multiply(src interface{}, n int, dstp interface{}) {
    srcv := reflect.ValueOf(src)
    result := reflect.MakeSlice(srcv.Type(), 0, srcv.Len()*n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        result = reflect.AppendSlice(result, srcv)
    }
    reflect.ValueOf(dstp).Elem().Set(result)
}

in := []string{"push", "pop"}
var out []string
repeat(in, 10, &out)

fmt.Println(out) // prints [push pop push pop push pop push pop push pop push pop push pop push pop push pop push pop]
```

Comment: In Go 1.18, you can implement that as a generic function: https://go.dev/play/p/uWDXFeh5d_o. No need for `reflect` anymore ;)